# Adding items to a list

Tags: c#

I have a list one for students and one for marks. I want to add student marks according to the id entered and then view the records. I'm not implementing it correctly. Can someone tell me how to do it correctly please?
This is the output I am trying to achieve:
1) add student
2)add marks: user will be asked to enter id and according to the id if it exists then marks will be stored according to that id.
3)View Marks: view student id and his marks

```
class Student
{     
    public Student(string name, string surname, string dob, string address)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Surname = surname;
        this.DOB = dob;
        this.Address = address;
    }

    public List<Marks> studentId = new List<Marks>();
    public List<Marks> Mathematics = new List<Marks>();
    public List<Marks> English = new List<Marks>();
    public List<Marks> Maltese = new List<Marks>();
    public List<Marks> ReligiousStudies = new List<Marks>();
    public List<Marks> SocialStudies = new List<Marks>();

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string Addr { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public Student(string s)
    {
        string[] splitted = s.Split(',');
        name = splitted[0];
        surname = splitted[1];
        dob = splitted[2];
        address = splitted[3];
        id = splitted[4];          
     }

    public void AddMarks(string id, int hyexam, int anexam)
    {
        if (Id.Equals(id))
        {
            studentId.Add(new Marks(id));
            Mathematics.Add(new Marks(hyexam, anexam));
            English.Add(new Marks(hyexam, anexam));
            Maltese.Add(new Marks(hyexam, anexam));
            ReligiousStudies.Add(new Marks(hyexam, anexam));
            SocialStudies.Add(new Marks(hyexam, anexam));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("id not found");
        }
    }

    public void StudMarks()
    {
        foreach (Marks mrk in studentId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mrk);
        }
        foreach (Marks mrk in Mathematics)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mrk);
        }

        foreach (Marks mrk in English)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mrk);
        }

        foreach (Marks mrk in Maltese)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mrk);
        }

        foreach (Marks mrk in ReligiousStudies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mrk);
        }            
     }           
   }
}

public class ClassYear 
{               
    private const string filestud = "C:\\Users\\Maria\\Desktop\\Students\\stud.txt";    
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public List<Student> mystudent=new List <Student> ();
    public List<Student> MyStud
    {
        get { return mystudent; }
    }

    public void Addstudent(string name,string surname,string dob, string addr)
    {
        mystudent.Add(new Student(name,surname,dob,addr));                   
    }

    private void LoadFromFile()
    {
        try
        {
            string s;
            StreamReader myFile = File.OpenText(filestud);
            while ((s = myFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Student st = new Student(s);
                mystudent.Add(st);
            }
            myFile.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was a file handling problem");
        }
    }

    private void DumpToFile()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter myFile = File.CreateText(filestud);
            foreach (Student s in mystudent)
            {
                myFile.WriteLine(s.ToString());
            }
            myFile.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was a file handling problem");
        }
    }

    private int SearchItem(int search)
    {
        int found = -1;
        if (mystudent != null)
        {
            foreach (Student st in mystudent)
            {
                found++;
                if (Student.Equals(search,st)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    private void Delete(int index)
    {
        SearchItem(index);
        mystudent.RemoveAt(index);
        foreach (Student st in mystudent) {
            Console.WriteLine(st);
        }            
    }

    private void EditItem(int index)        
    {
        Student stud = new Student();        
        SearchItem(index);
        mystudent[index] = stud;
        Console.WriteLine("current record is" + index);
        Console.WriteLine("enter new record:");
        stud.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        stud.Surname = Console.ReadLine();
        stud.Addr = Console.ReadLine();
        stud.Id = Console.ReadLine();
        foreach (Student st in mystudent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(st);
        }
    }
    private void ViewStudents()
    {
        foreach (Student st in mystudent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(st);
        }
    }                    
 }  
 }

public class Marks
{      
    public int HYEXAM { get; private set; }
    public int ANEXAM { get; private set; }
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public Marks(int hyexam, int anexam)
    {          
        this.HYEXAM = hyexam;
        this.ANEXAM = anexam;
    }

    public Marks(string id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public double OverallExam()
    {
        return (0.4 * HEYXAM) + (0.6 * ANEXAM);
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Wow... what a wall of code! For a start consider using [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). That would cut your program down to about half the number of lines. The remaining code would be the actual interesting code.

Comment: Maria, check out http://sscce.org/ to see if you can improve/shorten your code sample.

Comment: Can't see any possibility to find a mark for a student by a student id

Comment: @sll student marks are inside student, so it looks... so if you can locate a student, you can get them from there ;) but this is quite complicated in this code sample... ;)

Comment: Also, it may be kind of a problem to find marks you never add. I mean, there's implementation of `AddMarks` in class `Student`, but this method is never used

Comment: @Maria, I've slightly formatted source code but please spend some time doing this yourself when posting a new question next time and Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Maria, also, can you please show us a few samples of input and output... (what you are trying to achieve)? Oh, and if the question is homework, please specify that (in tags)

Comment: @poncha Homework tag has been deprecated

Comment: @MarkHall oh.. i'm outdated ;) i'll readup on meta ;) thanks for the info

Comment: The output that Im trying to achieve is the following: 1) Add student therefore: Name:"john" surname:"vella" dob:"2/1/1990" addres:"oxford street" id:"34343". 2) I want to iput marks based on the id so  the program asks user to enter the id of the student and checks if the id exists or not. Based on the Id marks will be added.  3) Show id and marks of students for examlple id:34353 Mathematics hyexam:75 anexam:80 etc..

Comment: @poncha I wanted to read about the homework tag also. Here is the official Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/134987

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from what I can tell, you have a list of students. Each of these students has several lists of marks: Mathematics, English, Maltese, etc.

So let's say you want to add a Mathematics mark to a certain student. Assuming you have:

```
List<Student> students;
int userId; // the id entered by the user
Mark mathMark; // the mark you want to add
```

Search the list for the given id:

```
foreach (Student myStudent in students)
{
    if (myStudent.Id == userId)
    {
        myStudent.Mathematics.Add(mathMark);
    }
}
```

Then when you want to display all the math marks for your student:

```
foreach (Mark mark in myStudent.Mathematics)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mark.HYEXAM + "," + mark.ANEXAM);
}
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: I'm not experienced with LINQ and I can't use it for this particular program