# Dictionary to a list

Tags: c#

How can you use a value of a dictionary to map it to a list. For example I have `Dictionary<int,int> studid= new Dictionary<int,int>();` where index will be the key and id will be the value. Now I have a list of marks.

How can I point the id to the list of marks and display them?

Comment: You don't have a list of marks per key. You have a single `int` value per key.

Comment: Is having a `Dictionary<int, List<Marks>>` acceptable?

Answer (score 4):

You are using an incorrect data type for your needs. You need a dictionary mapping a key to a *list* of integers:

```
Dictionary<int,List<int>> studid= new Dictionary<int,List<int>>();
```

You would use the key in order to get the list of marks:

```
var marks = studid[theIndex];
```

Comment: I am using a list of marks. How can I map it the lists to the dictionary:  public List<Marks> Mathematics = new List<Marks>();
        public List<Marks> English = new List<Marks>();
        public List<Marks> Maltese = new List<Marks>();
        public List<Marks> ReligiousStudies = new List<Marks>();
        public List<Marks> SocialStudies = new List<Marks>();

Comment: This seems to be a continuation of her question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691882/adding-items-to-a-list . I'm still not entirely sure why a Dictionary object is involved.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` is the simplest way. Your key will be an int, and the value can be a list of marks.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
dict.Add(1, new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```